# How do I fix Memoir's header "Contents" in the Sniplets section?

Tags: macros, header-footer, memoir

In [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) I really like the way how custom entities are being referred to, such as the sniplets in its [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf). It lets you define a set of items just like Figures and Tables. I'm reusing this code for other purposes, but I noticed a small glitch that's also present in the memoir manual itself. All pages in the Sniplets section have a header "Contents" as shown below.

[image]

I suspect that something in the `\sniplettoc` macro is causing this. The relevant lines from the [`memsty.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/doc-src/memsty.sty) file:

```
%%%% SNIPLETS %%%%
\newcounter{sniplet}
\counterwithin{sniplet}{chapter}
\newcommand*\snipletname{Sniplet}
\newcommand*\snipletref[1]{\snipletname~\ref{#1} on~\pref{#1}}
\newenvironment{sniplet}[1][]{
  \refstepcounter{sniplet}
  \edef\mem@e{\@ifnotmtarg{#1}{~(#1)}}
  \section*{\snipletname~\thesniplet\mem@e}
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\snipletname\ \thesniplet\mem@e}
  \renewenvironment{lcode}{%\@zeroseps
    \renewcommand{\verbatim@startline}{\verbatim@line{\hskip\gparindent}}
    \small\setlength{\baselineskip}{\onelineskip}\verbatim}%
  {\endverbatim
    \vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}%
    \noindent}
}{}

\let\normalchangetocdepth\changetocdepth
\newcommand\sniplettoc{%
  \setcounter{@memmarkcntra}{\value{tocdepth}}%
  \begingroup%
  \let\changetocdepth\@gobble%
  \normalchangetocdepth{-10}%
  \cftinsertcode{start-sniplets}{\normalchangetocdepth{3}}%
  \cftinsertcode{end-sniplets}{\normalchangetocdepth{-10}}%
  \let\tocheadstart\relax%\@gobble
  % \printtoctitle\@gobble
  \renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\section*{Sniplet overview}}%
  \let\aftertoctitle\relax%
  \let\printtocnonum\relax%
  \let\precistoctext\@gobble%
  \setlength\cftsectionindent{0pt}%
  \tableofcontents*
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{@memmarkcntra}}
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The headers and footers are usually constructed in `memoir` with the series of commands connect to `\makepagestyle` and then called with `\pagestyle`; so either one of the commands in your own snippets is tacitly calling the equivalent of `\pagestyle{contents}` or there is a real mix-up going on.  You can always override it by using your own `\makepagestyle` commands if you can't find the source of the confusion.  Incidentally, in an older(? -- from 2011 03 06) version, the headers for that section are correct.

Comment: @jon This odd behaviour I showed in my question is demonstrated by the published prebuilt `memman.pdf`. I guess this is a bug. As I am unable to find any project page for `memoir`, I guess I'd have to contact the maintainer.

Comment: Absolutely: you should contact the maintainer about typos and other errata in the manual.  I was [1] trying to suggest that the problem was unlikely to lie in the code snippet you posted, and [2] how you can in the meantime create your own page styles: `\makepagestyle{tempsnippets}\makeevenhead{tempsnippets}{<...>}{<...>}{<...>}\makeoddhead{tempsnippets}{<...>}{<...>}{<...>}\makeevenfoot{tempsnippets}{<...>}{<...>}{<...>}\makeoddfoot{tempsnippets}{<...>}{<...>}{<...>}` and then call the page style at the appropriate place in your document.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I guess what is happening is `\sniplettoc` calls `\tableofcontents*`, which calls in turn gives you the `\contentsname` in the header.  Sniplets are classed as a 'section', however, so your headers need to be designed to include sectional information, and it is not clear what you are doing without an [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Answer (score 2):

*Many thanks to [jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8528/jon) providing the clue in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127859/how-do-i-fix-memoirs-header-contents-in-the-sniplets-section?noredirect=1#comment287756_127859), so I'm posting this as CW.*

As I guessed, the small Table Of Contents of the Sniplets is causing trouble here. [jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8528/jon) put me in the right direction and by rewriting the `\tableofcontents*` part in `memsty.sty` for the "Sniplets Overview" I got the result I expected. I've replaced

```
\tableofcontents*
```

on line 1088 in that file with

```
\printtoctitle{}
\@starttoc{toc}%
```

to prevent having the `\tableofcontents*` override any of the things in the header.

I'll inform Lars Madsen (the current maintainer I believe) to get this sorted in the memoir package.